# App Script code returns Error. "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange') Validation @ Code.gs:5"

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is my code a sample data. I am wanting to compare Sheet 1 data to sheet 2 data and return "True" in column C if the value in that row is in the other list.

```
    function Validation() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Tranactions');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName("Cat");
  var sh1rg=sh1.getRange(1,2,sh1.getLastRow()); 
  var sh2rg=sh2.getRange(1,1);
  var sh1cvA=sh1rg.getValues();
  var sh2cV=sh2rg.getValue();//look here
  for(var i=0;i<sh1cvA.length-1; i++){
    if(sh1cvA[i][0]==sh2cV){
      sh1.getRange(i+2,3).setValue("True");
    }
  }
}
```

| Sheet 1 |
| --- |
| Eggs |
| Bacon |
| Bread |
| Tea |
| Milk |
| Sugar |

| Sheet 2 |
| --- |
| Cereal |
| Towels |
| Milk |
| Wine |
| Sugar |
| Bananas |
| Eggs |
| Bread |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's the modified version of your script comparing the data in Sheet 1 to Sheet 2:**

```
  function validation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Tranactions');
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Cat");
  var sh1rg = sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var sh2rg = sh2.getRange(1,1,sh2.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  for(var i = 0; i < sh1rg.length; i++){
    if(sh2rg.indexOf(sh1rg[i][0])>=0){
      sh1.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("True");
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the expected result:

[image]

**Reference:**

- [indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple of small mistakes.  I suspect you meant to start at line 2

```
function Validation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Tranactions');
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Cat");
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange(1, 2, sh1.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var v2 = sh2.getRange(1, 1).getValue();
  for (var i = 0; i < vs1.length; i++) {
    if (vs1[i][0] == v2) {
      sh1.getRange(i + 2, 3).setValue("True");
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you actually wanted it this way:

```
function Validation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//changed sheetname
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//changed sheetname
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange(1, 1, sh1.getLastRow()).getValues()
  var vs2 = sh2.getRange(1, 1, sh2.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();//this is now a list instead of a single value
  for (var i = 0; i < vs1.length; i++) {
    if (~vs2.indexOf(vs1[i][0])) {
      sh1.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue("True");
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Sheet0:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Eggs |  | TRUE |
| 2 | Bacon |  |  |
| 3 | Bread |  | TRUE |
| 4 | Tea |  |  |
| 5 | Milk |  | TRUE |
| 6 | Sugar |  | TRUE |

and my Sheet1:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cereal |
| 2 | Towels |
| 3 | Milk |
| 4 | Wine |
| 5 | Sugar |
| 6 | Bananas |
| 7 | Eggs |
| 8 | Bread |

- [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [bitwise not ~](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

Comment: It returns an empty value. :/

Comment: That's correct  because sh2 row 1 col 1 is cereal and there is no cereal in sheet 1